# XML: Avoiding/default value for xs:extension

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm dealing with an XML schema which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="XML" type="XMLType"/>
   <xs:complexType name="client_summaryType">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="true">
      <xs:extension base="xs:any"><xs:sequence><xs:any processContents="skip" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /></xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="cid"/>
        <!-- other attributes -->
        <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip" /></xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="XMLType">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="client_summaryType" name="client_summary"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
attribute 'base': The QName value '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}any' does not resolve to a(n) simple type definition.
```

Now, my problem is, how do I avoid the `xs:extension` trap? I can't use `base="xs:string"` because I want to include elements within `client_summaryType`. Apparently, I can't use `xs:element` or `xs:any` as well. What can I use, to still use `complexContent`, not have it inherit stuff from anywhere, just let me define what I want and validate against that? So, I don't want to deal with `xs:extension` problems, but I do want to use `xs:complexContent` (so validate against content). Can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xs:extension base="xs:anyType">`

Answer (score 0):

There is no type called xs:any, so you can't extend it. Perhaps you were thinking of xs:anyType? But I'm not sure why you would want to extend that, since it already allows everything. It seems to me from your description of what you are trying to achieve that you should omit both the xs:complexContent and the xs:extension, and simply define your content model as a child of xs:complexType.

Comment: Hey Michael, I tried that, but I got errors with '[$element] cannot have content with it's type empty' or something along those lines.